# ClassNotFound With URLClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I currently have the following directory tree structure:

```
CLASSES  
  -> ClassOne  
     ->package
        -> my
           ->App.class
```

I would like to load the App.class from my local drive. I looked around, particularly stackoverflow, and most seem to suggest that I should use the URLClassLoader.

In order to do this, I used this following code:

However, I get a ClassNotFoundError. Can anybody help me please.

```
 String url = "file://" + classOneFolder.getAbsolutePath(); //Where classesFolder is a File representing the ClassOne directory

 URL[] urls = {new URL(url)};
 urlClassLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);                    

 //class loader needs the fully classified class name. Therefore:
 Class appClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("package.my.App");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `classOneFolder.toURI().toURL()` instead of building the URL yourself as a String and then recreate a URL from it. On some systems (like Windows) you need to add another slash in front on the absolute filename for a valid URL. Using [File.toURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI%28%29)[.toURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#toURL%28%29) should always build a correct URL.

Comment: I was going to take that approach, but my IDE is telling me that the method is deprecated

Comment: Yes, in Java 6 `File.toURL()` is deprecated. But the JavaDoc was also updated and suggests to use `FILE.toURI().toURL()` instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it found it now